# Python CSV file reading not working

Tags: python, file, csv

Im am having this code:

```
import csv
file = csv.reader(open("population.csv"))
file.next()
['country', 'country isocode', 'year', 'POP']
```

But for some reason my python client wont call up the file and show nothing in the shell beside:

```
>>> ===================================RESTART================================
>>>
>>>
```

I know that the file population.csv isnt corrupted or written wrong because i just had to download this file for an asigment so can annyone please help me with this problem ?

the result that i am having to have is that i will print a excel file in my shell, its kinda hard to show cause im not having 10 reputation yet so im not allowed to print anny pitures but the excel file looks like this:

A
1country,"country isocode","year","POP"
2Netherlands,"NLD","1950","10113.527"
3Netherlands,"NLD","1951","10264.311"
4Netherlands,"NLD","1952","10381.988"
5Netherlands,"NLD","1953","10493.184"
6Netherlands,"NLD","1954","10615.38"
7Netherlands,"NLD","1955","10750.842"
8Netherlands,"NLD","1956","10889.351"
9Netherlands,"NLD","1957","11026.383"
10Netherlands,"NLD","1958","11186.875"

Comment: What is that list doing in your code snippet? What output are you expecting?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, my ***guess*** is that's the output from interactive interpreter after `file.next()` -- looks like a reasonable return value.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @jedwards I try not to assume anything. Just as likely that the OP has put that exact code into a file he/she is trying to run, and is confused at the lack of output.

Comment: Fair enough, point well taken.

Answer (score 0):

If you have that code in a .py file and are trying to run it, then you should explicitly print the lines out. Like this:

```
import csv
file = csv.reader(open("population.csv"))
print file.next()
```

Running code in interactive Python shell will show you the values immediately, but having the same code in a file and running it will not show anything - unless you output it in some way